# how to initialize array with null in qt GUI application?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, null, initialization

```
char totalbuffer[2048] = {0};
```

this is the initialization of array I want. I had tried to put in main.cpp and my header file,qt creator keep show the error.

this is my .h header file code :

```
#ifndef QTPROJECT2_H
#define QTPROJECT2_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtNetwork/QHostAddress>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QUdpSocket>
#include <QString>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QDataStream>
#include <qstring.h>
#include <QStandardItem>

namespace Ui {
class QtProject2;
}

class QtProject2 : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit QtProject2(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~QtProject2();
    void start(QString address, quint16 port);
    char totalbuffer[2048]={0};
    QStandardItemModel* ListModel;

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

public slots:
    void startTransfer();
    void disconnected();
    void readyRead();



signals:
    void socketReady();


private:
    Ui::QtProject2 *ui;
    QTcpSocket *client;

};


#endif // QTPROJECT2_H
```

this is my main.cpp coding:

```
    #include "qtproject2.h"
    #include <QApplication>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        QtProject2 w;
        w.show();
        char totalbuffer[2048]={0};
        return a.exec();
    }
```

this is my project qtproject2.cpp:
    #include "qtproject2.h"
    #include "ui_qtproject2.h"

```
QtProject2::QtProject2(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::QtProject2)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

QtProject2::~QtProject2()
{
    delete ui;
    QtProject2 Client2;
    Client2.close();

}


void QtProject2::startTransfer()
{
  ui->slabel->setText("Connected!");
}

void QtProject2::disconnected()
{
    ui->slabel->setText("Disconnected!");
}

void QtProject2::readyRead()
{

    client->waitForBytesWritten(1000);
    client->waitForReadyRead(3000);
    char CustomerData_MacAdd[][18]={"14:13:12:11:67:11","52:22:22:22:22:22", "14:22:44:55:22" };
    char CustomerData_Username[][10]={"Robert","Alex","Ivan"};

    QByteArray buffer1 = client->readLine();
    char *temp = buffer1.data();
    char buffer[1024]={0};

    if (strncmp(temp,"*CLIENT",6)==0)
    {
        int j;
        for(j=9;j<26;j++)
        { buffer[j-9]=temp[j];}
    }else if(strncmp(temp,"*ALERT",5)==0)
    {
        int j;
        for(j=8;j<25;j++)
        {buffer[j-8]=temp[j];}
    }

    //char totalbuffer[2048]={0};

    int k;
    for (k=0;k<3;k++){
              if (strncmp(buffer,CustomerData_MacAdd[k],16)==0){
                  strncat(totalbuffer,"User is in Queue : ",19);
                  strncat (totalbuffer,CustomerData_Username[k],size_t(CustomerData_Username[k]));
                  strncat(totalbuffer,"\n",2);

                  ui->label->setText(totalbuffer);

        }}

    ui->slabel->setText(buffer1);

}

void QtProject2::on_pushButton_clicked()
{ 
    client = new QTcpSocket(this);
    connect(client, SIGNAL(connected()),this, SLOT(startTransfer()));
    connect(client, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnected()));
    connect(client, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()));


    /*Connect to User Define Port Address*/
    client->connectToHost("127.0.0.1", 1234);
}
```

Focus for the char totalbuffer[2048]={0}; , i really no idea where i should put it. 
I had searched with google and stackoverflow, all the method is using class and call in the .cpp file. but my one is GUI application,that's different with console.

What should i do? I really need a help. Appreciate the helps and thanks you guys~

EDITED***
this is the error shows.

```
error assigning to an array from an initializer list
```

I think the initialize list can't put in the header file and main.cpp so how i going to initialize an array? like C++ visual studio by using public variable....

Comment: Why don't you show us the error? Also, you should use `QString` or `QByteArray` to operate char arrays.

Comment: Show *what* error? Please edit your question with more complete code (preferably a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)), and also please add the complete and unedited list of errors you have.

Comment: sorry guys..i had edited. I'm develop a qt GUI application,have a main.cpp qtproject2.h qtproject2.cpp 
i don't know where to put for the public initialize list

Answer (score 0):

You can use the memset or bzero functions

```
memset((void*)&totalbuffer, 0, sizeof(totalbuffer));
```

or

```
bzero((void*)&totalbuffer, sizeof(totalbuffer));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to Qt, but basic C++.

Class members are initialized in the constructor. You can just use `std::fill` there.